# Create multiple bar graphs out of a single data table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graph, illustrator

I have data for obesity rates and alcohol consumption for 20 different countries, all in the same data table. I want to create 20 separate bar graphs, which I can then place over each country to show these two statistics for that specific country rather than one single bar graph for everything. Is there any way I can do this in ArcMap or Adobe Illustrator? Or do I have to separate the data into 20 tables?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with a single table depending on what exactly you want the result to look like. The graphs produced will be very simple and have no labels, so they basically just show relative amounts. For more detailed graphs then yes, you may need to separate the data because [normal graphs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003300000047000000) look at selected values for all rows, not multiple values for a single row.

You need to use [Chart Symbology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000003000000) to do it, and detailed instructions can be found on that help page. The basics are going to the Symbology Tab for the country layer (assuming your stats are attributes of that layer, or at least joined to it) and choosing Charts under the Show heading, then adding the two stat fields (obesity and alcohol consumption) under the Field Selection heading.

Note that you'll want your two attributes to have similar ranges otherwise one column may be significantly larger in each chart than the other. This may require normalizing the data - without seeing an example of your data I can't say.